# Как назвать список предстоящих дел?

Tags: одним-словом, словарь

Есть ли в русском языке название для списка дел, которые предстоит выполнить, и, может быть, выполнить не в самое ближайшее время, списка отложенных дел? В английском языке, например, для этого можно использовать краткое, но ёмкое слово **backlog**, одно из значений которого как раз соответствует такому накопившемуся набору дел.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В словаре "Английский язык: вчера, сегодня и завтра", Брайан Локетт. «Русский язык — Медиа», 2005, значение слова **backlog** описывается так:

> Запас, задел. Британцы позаимствовали это очень полезное слово у американцев. Буквально оно значит большое бревно, положенное глубоко в камин, чтобы поддерживать огонь. В Америке это слово употребляется с позитивным оттенком, таким образом, американский бизнесмен рад иметь *a backlog of orders* (портфель заказов). В Великобритании же это слово приобрело негативное значение, означая кучу накопившейся работы из-за забастовок или других непредвиденных обстоятельств. В Америке радостно говорят о *a backlog*, а в Англии — с кислым выражением лица. *It will take several years to clear the backlog of political asylum applications*. — Потребуется несколько лет, чтобы рассмотреть огромное количество заявлений о предоставлении политического убежища.

В свете этого могу предложить такие варианты:

- невыполненные заказы / планы
- задолженность [по заказам]
- отставание [от плана, графика]
- незавершённая работа, незавершённые задания
- накопившиеся дела
- неразобранные дела

Comment: В Северной Америке употребление слова "backlog" лучше всего перевести как "завал". Обычно слово это характеризует запущенное состояние дел, для приведение в порядок которых требуются значительные усилия. У этого слова почти всегда депрессивная эмоциональная окраска.

Comment: Да, в словаре я видел примерно то же самое. Я же надеюсь найти одно слово славянского происхождения, имеющее положительный оттенок, обозначающее именно такой список задач, пополняющийся новыми задачами и сокращающийся после исполнения более старых. "Неразобранные дела", только одним словом.

Comment: @Anvar Встретился с этим термином по работе. Особого негативного оттенка не заметил. В моем случае это означало "список дел которые хорошо было бы сделать, но пока есть более срочные или важные дела".

Comment: @krokoziabla - Если вам нужно именно одно слово,тогда можно сказать "неразобранное", "запланированное". Но вообще-то, не всегда и не каждое слово на другой язык можно перевести тоже одним словом.

Comment: @YellowSky Просто чем больше изучаю английский, тем более замечаю в русском языке множество пришлых латинских и других слов. Для того, что по-английски можно выразить одним словом, в русском языке часто приходится подбирать целое словосочетание. Неужели русский язык изначально не был достаточно богат, что пришлось тащить слова из других языков? Впрочем, я не говорю о таких словах, например, как погуглить или интерференция, описывающие явления, открытые или придуманные за границей.

Comment: @krokoziabla в английском языке латинских заимствований больше, чем в русском.

Comment: @krokoziabla - Языки не бывают "изначально недостаточно богатыми". На английский русское "полуночничать" вам тоже одним словом перевести не удастся, а на русский нельзя одним словом перевести такие элементарные английские слова как "toe" и "thumb". Просто семантические поля слов каждого языка устроены по-своему в каждом языке, если они совпадают - это большая редкость.

Comment: @Artemix: "список дел которые хорошо было бы сделать, но пока есть более срочные или важные дела" - для описания этой ситуации больше подходит слово "backburner". "Backlog" это дела которые не хорошо бы сделать, а рано или поздно сделать необходимо.

Comment: @Anvar В том-то и дело что именно такое слово (backlog) нам североамериканцы и придумали. И их действительно рано или поздно сделать необходимо, но в этом нет никакой проблемы - это не "завал".

Comment: "задел" не подходит. задел - это что-то УЖЕ сделанное наперед с учётом, что оно будет полезным в будущем. http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB

Answer (score 0):

долгосрочная программа

долгосрочный план

намеченное

задания

Comment: Смею заметить, что план и программа - это заимствованные слова. :-)

Comment: @krokoziabla и что?

Comment: Я же ищу слово со славянскими корнями.

Comment: @krokoziabla в вопросе об этом ничего не сказанно.

Answer (score 0):

Задачи. 
 
План (на сегодня, месяц, год).